# html value is truncating my string

Tags: javascript, html, input, truncate

On my page I am using HTML5 to upload a file on my browser. The file is a PDF an have to show it in a `<input type="text"/>`

This is my code:

```
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    console.log(f.name);
    console.log(f.type);
    console.log(f.size);

    //Update document info
    $("#document_filename").find("input").val(f.name);
    $("#document_mimetype").find("input").val(f.type);


    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onloadend = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
        content = e.target.result.replace(/^data:[^;]*;base64,/, "");
        console.log(content.length);
        $("#document_content").find("input").val(content);
        a = document.getElementById("document_content").getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        a.value = content;
        console.log(a.value.length);
        };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);

}
```

When I upload a big file 1.5MB, my console is showing:

```
    contrat.pdf             // The file name
    application/pdf         // The file type
    1510788                 // The file size
    2014384                 // The length of the b64 content
    524288                  // The length of string once inserted in the input box??
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong to get this data truncated?

Thanks,

Comment: First thing would be to make sure that `document.getElementById("document_content").getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` returns the same element as `$("#document_content").find("input").val(content)`. Why are you doing that anyway? Second, do you have any validation around the `<input>`? `maxlength`?

Comment: Hi, it's returning the same. I am doing that because I am writing Jquery and when I inputbox trucated I have written this line in native js to avoid jquery bug. And I am still having the same behavior...

Comment: The HTML code is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp), the maximum length possible for an `input` of type text seems to be 524288 at least on Chrome. And this is what you have...

I suggest you storing your value in another place!

---

**EDIT :**

The implementation varies across browsers : on FF (v32), I can have length greater than 524288 (I have tested up to 10.000.000), but on Chrome it is limitated to 524288 even though we increase the `maxlength` attribute.

There is also an open ticket for WebKit about this issue : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44883

Comment: Thx for the info. This is what I am looking for... but how do you understand it? That the default value of maxlength is 524288? Or the max value is 524288 absolutely? What do you suggest to store it? A textarea?

Comment: Why do you need to display it? You can only store it to some JS variable?

Comment: I do need to display. The user may edit this value (for example copy/paste it from another input box...)

Comment: Copy / paste binary data??? Perhaps propose a button that allow to add this value to the clipboard but the display of this value seems strange. BTW, I have updated my answer with some remarks...

Comment: Note that W3Schools makes that statement without reference to any specification or standard. There is no such limit in HTML5 or various DOM standards. The answers to [*is there a max size to the length of a hidden input in html*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752768/is-there-a-max-size-to-the-length-of-a-hidden-input-in-html) might be useful. So while 524288 might be a limit in some browsers, it is not specified anywhere and likely is different in different browsers, or even different versions of the same browser.

Comment: @RobG, yes I know, but see my edit, it seems to be implemented like this on WebKit and the ticket looks like to be forgotten (always open)...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie—yes, but better to say "you have likely hit the limit for input elements in that browser" or similar rather than state it as a limit for input elements in general.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie : Copy/Paste b64 data => Text. Thanks for the test under FF. I am using Chrome and my app should run under Chrome. I have changed my input box into textarea and it's working then.

Comment: @RobG I changed my implementation to use textarea. It's not acceptable in my case to show this kind of message. My app should allow the end user to edit a very long string. Thank you guys, I am happy with that :-)