# base64 string in input field gets truncated

Tags: php, google-chrome, php-7, apache2.4

I am using [this file uploader plugin](https://github.com/Cerealkillerway/fileUploader), which uses javascript's FileReader API to read files and put them in input elements as base64 strings. Those files could be up to 5mb, so the base64 strings could become quite long.

Anyway, at first everything seems to be working correctly: I can select a file and inspect my hidden input's content, and the base64 string is equal to what I can obtain by using the base64 command on my linux machine: `base64 file.pdf > file.b64`.

The problem is that, when I post the form, the string gets truncated after 524261 characters, missing the last 50000 chars (more or less). Which means that the file is corrupt.

I have tried changing some php setting (through the .htaccess file), but it's still not working, and honestly I can't figure out what the problem could be...

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Comment: What is `memory_limit` set to in your php.ini file? (You can check this with a simple php file containing: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`)

Comment: Add `AllowOverride Options` in your virtual host configuration file and then reload Apache.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1752768/794749

Comment: @icecub actually it's 128MB.

Comment: If I enable AllowOverride Options, apache crashes with error `RewriteEngine not allowed here`...

Comment: Maybe problem in coded data? I think you must use base64 url format (read in wiki about base64 url)

Comment: After a few more tests, I see that problem is present with chrome, but firefox is sending the complete string. Looks like the problem is not related to apache/php...

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was actually chrome (I suppose some other browsers could have the same issue too). I have solved it by using a textarea instead of an input. Since the fileUploader plugin that I was using doesn't support textareas instead of inputs for the file content, I will probably do a pull request with the fix. Thank you gre_gor for pointing out the browser issue, thank you all for your help.