# Ajax Post data lost if input length is big

Tags: ajax, symfony, semantic-ui, sylius

I work an a Sylius project.

In the `sylius_shop_ajax_cart_add_item` form I added a custom input of type `hidden` where I send a base64 image.

The problem is that if the input is big the POST data is lost.

The ajax call is made via Semantic UI js API.

Here is the request with some small input data. The field to pay attention is `image_base64`.
[image]

And here is the expected result on the server, debugger stopped at the first line of the controller.
[image]

Here is the image of the html with `image_base64` input

[image]

And here is the debugger right on the first line of the controller.

[image]

I use the built in server from Symfony.

My php config for `max_post_size` is 8mb.

Please someone any suggestion where is the problem?

Comment: have you tried grabbing the string from the input value field in the html viewer and checking if the image loads?

Comment: Yes the image is a valid image, also the idea is that the whole data is lost.

Comment: I debugged in the semantic ui js and in the beforeSend hook of the api/ajax call the data is present. Then it somehow gets lost. Kind of black magic

Comment: maybe the error is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752768/is-there-a-max-size-to-the-length-of-a-hidden-input-in-html

Comment: @Danimal good point let me check it