# What is maximum charachters that can be set in Value attribute of a hidden HTML input element?

Tags: html, forms, input, hidden, hidden-field

```
<input type="hidden" value="12345">
```

I need to set value="12345" attribute to the size of 5,000 characters. What is a max characters I can set this attribute to when using POST method to send a form? Is it limited by the maximum POST method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a max size to the length of a hidden input in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752768/is-there-a-max-size-to-the-length-of-a-hidden-input-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are using the POST or GET method for your form action.

More comprehensive answers are already available such as here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I use POST method

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless 
  There is no limit on the number of FORM elements you can pass via POST, but only on the aggregate size of all name/value pairs. While GET is limited to as low as 1024 characters, POST data is limited to 2 MB on IIS 4.0, and 128 KB on IIS 5.0.

Comment: Tnx @jcklopp. That's what I wanted to know.